# what happens if we does not subscribe to HttpClient request which return observables in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, angular-httpclient

I am new to Angular & typescript , trying to understand **HttpClient**, **observables** & **subscribe**

When i do this in a function of a component

```
console.log(this.http.get('assets/user.json'));
```

I am receiving an object but can not see any request going to `https://localhost:4200/assets/user.json` in debugger `network` while if i change code to

```
this.http.get('assets/userDetail.json').subscribe(data => this.user = { name:  data['name']});
```

I can see the network request hitting the required URL. why this is happening ? my understanding was `this.http.get('assets/userDetail.json')` will hit the url even if we does not subscribe to response data stream.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To understand the matter it's good to know there are **hot** & **cold** observables - the cold need to be subscribed otherwise they're not fired, the hot are fired no matter if something is subscribed to them.

Angular's HttpClient returns a cold Observable, so it's not fired until subscribed. To be sure if an observable is hot or cold you need to check corresponding docs, see for example [HttpClient.post](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post):

> Constructs an Observable which, **when subscribed**, will cause the
>   configured POST request to be executed on the server.

An example of an Angular's hot observable is e.g. [ActivatedRoute.params - how to use](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#how-to-use) - you see there is no subscription.

The fact an observable is hot/cold has more consequences than just having or not having to subscribe:

- when subscribing, you should also unsubscribe [in some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription) to avoid memory leaks plus there is Angular's [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe), which manages subscription for you; there is an article on the matter: [Don't forget to unsubscribe](http://brianflove.com/2016/12/11/anguar-2-unsubscribe-observables/) (Angular specific)
- there is a perfect article by Ben Lesh on the subject from a general point of view: [Hot vs Cold Observables](https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339) (not specific to Angular).

Comment: Really complete answer, +1

Comment: would be great to have an option to make the respective call hot

Answer (score 1):

It's worth to mention that assuming code like that and cold observable:

(pseudo-code)

**Component:**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('Before, in ngInit')
    usersService.usersGet();
    console.log('After, in ngInit')
}
```

**Service:**

```
public usersGet(){
   console.log("I'm in service");
   let data = this.http.get('assets/user.json')
   console.log("I'm already here")
   return data;
}
```

you will see such ouput in dev tools in browser:

[image]

but your backend endpoint **will not** receive any request.

your backend will get request thought when you will change code to:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('Before, in ngInit')
    usersService.usersGet().subscribe( x=> {
        console.log("I'm inside of subscribe")
        console.log(x)
    });
    console.log('After, in ngInit')
}
```

and output will be:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer already explained why it won't work without any subscribers. Because it's a *cold observer*, so it will be executed only when it found at least one subscriber.

So the alternative is basically:

```
 this.http.get('assets/user.json').subscribe();
```

Answer (score 0):

Overview: in this code snippet I create an webapi service using injectable that is visibile to the whole application.  I subscribe to the observable returned by http.get from the callling function.  The result of IView is bound to the data list similar to a promise.  Now the WebApiService can be injected in other components constructor.

myComponent.component.ts

```
 public data: IDataView[];
```

Call the observable.
this.app.getMyViews('123').subscribe(result=>{this.data=result;});

WebApi.service.ts

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})

```
export class WebApiService
{
   constructor(private http: HttpClient,private env:             EnvironmentUrlService) {     }

getMyViews(id)
    {
        var path = this.env.urlAddress + '/my_class/GetData/'+id;
        return this.http.get<IDataView[]>(path);

  }
```

}